# Git Remote Access in Azure Pipelines, possible?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to achieve the following through the build pipeline.

- Default branch: SIT (from the Azure Repos repository)
- Trigger: whenever a change is made in DEV branch

In a powershell task do the following:

- Merge latest from DEV to the current SIT branch
- Deploy the latest from SIT branch
- Push the updated SIT branch to the upstream repository

Here is my code:

```
git checkout -b temp
git merge origin/DEV
git branch -f SIT temp
git checkout SIT
git status
git branch -d temp
git remote add neworigin $(RemoteOrigin)
git push -u origin --all
```

When I try to push the updated SIT branch using `git push -u origin SIT` and I'm getting the following error:

> remote: 0000000000aaTF401027: You need the Git 'GenericContribute'
>   permission to perform this action. Details: identity
>   'Build\d073f6c7-4fa2-4bda-8694-8a41fb808fff', scope 'repository'.
>   remote: TF401027: You need the Git 'GenericContribute' permission to
>   perform this action. Details: identity
>   'Build\d073f6c7-4fa2-4bda-8694-8a41fb808fff', scope 'repository'.
>   fatal: unable to access '': The requested URL returned
>   error: 403

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue with git commands in Azure Pipelines.  The reason is that any commands that access the origin server, such as `git push` need to done by a user that has the credentials to do so.  In your situation, your PowerShell script is running in the user context of `Project Collection Build Service (yourProjectName)` and it does not have the permissions to contribute to your repo by default.

See this answer, I think it will fix you up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56542631/11767897